# How to change/update user role? Yii2

Tags: yii2-user, yii2-rbac, yii2-user-roles

I'm using yii2 role based access control (RBAC) system. I defined roles and permissions, defined rules, assigned roles to users.  Everything works fine.

but i  want to update assigned roles to users. For example:

```
Yii::$app->authManager->assign('admin', '11');
```

Here i did user id 11 admin. Now i want to update and change. I want to make this user manager.

When i try:

```
Yii::$app->authManager->assign('manager', '11');
```

This user have admin + manager. I just want to update this user role admin to manager.

How can i do this?

Answer (score 4):

first you [revoke()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#revoke()-detail.) or [revokeAll()](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-rbac-dbmanager.html#revoke()-detail.) user role:

Remove current role 'admin':

```
$manager = Yii::$app->authManager;
$item = $manager->getRole('admin');
$item = $item ? : $manager->getPermission('admin');
$manager->revoke($item,'11');
```

and again update new role to user:

```
$authorRole = $manager->getRole('manager');
$manager->assign($authorRole, 11);
```